# Count to 20 with Words!

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, natural-language

Using the following length-separated lists of words:

[https://github.com/Magic Octopus Urn/wordListsByLength](https://github.com/carusocomputing/wordListsByLength)

Print 1 word from each list of length `n`  from 1 all the way up to 20, here's a valid example:

```
a
an
and
hand
hands
handle
handles
abandons
abandoned
understand
outstanding
newfoundland
understanding
characteristic
characteristics
characterization
characterizations
characteristically
characterologically
chemotherapeutically
```

Alternatively (array):

```
['a', 'an', 'and', 'hand', 'hands', 'handle', 'handles', 'abandons', 'abandoned', 'understand', 'outstanding', 'newfoundland', 'understanding', 'characteristic', 'characteristics', 'characterization', 'characterizations', 'characteristically', 'characterologically', 'chemotherapeutically']
```

Alternatively (any printable non-alphabetic separator other than `\n`):

```
a:an:and:hand:hands:handle:handles:abandons:abandoned:understand:outstanding:newfoundland:understanding:characteristic:characteristics:characterization:characterizations:characteristically:characterologically:chemotherapeutically
```

---

## Rules

- You may choose your own 20 words.
- The words must be from the github page provided, more specifically:

  - 1 from 1.txt, 1 from 2.txt, etc...
  - Note, files above 20.txt exist, but you do not need any words above 20 characters.
- Valid separators are ASCII-printable non-alphabetical characters (even numbers, don't care).
- Lowercase or uppercase only, pick one, stick with it; no title-case allowed.
- Please don't use a 100% copy of my example 20 words...

  - You can, but that's no fun.
  - *They are likely suboptimal anyways...*
- If you DON'T want to use the separated files, and need a full list:

  - Use [unsorted.txt](https://github.com/carusocomputing/wordListsByLength/blob/master/unsorted.txt), this is all `n`.txt files in one, sorted alphabetically.
- Note, you CANNOT directly read from the URL, it is a [common loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1062/53748).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count will be the winner.

---

*For reference, the output is 229 bytes, so anything that gets under that beats hardcoding.*

---

Possible meta-tag-discussion:

[user-driven](/questions/tagged/user-driven) where the user gets to customize their outputs from a list of possibilities?

Comment: Following your links got me [here](http://www.greenworm.net/sites/default/files/gw-assets/enable1-wwf-v4.0-wordlist.txt), can I use that list?

Comment: @LiefdeWen that list is equivalent to this list: [unsorted.txt](https://github.com/carusocomputing/wordListsByLength/blob/master/unsorted.txt) so, yes. If you want to have a full-list of words to parse, use [unsorted.txt](https://github.com/carusocomputing/wordListsByLength/blob/master/unsorted.txt) or that.

Comment: As someone from Newfoundland, I appreciate the shoutout. :)

Comment: @Christian You could say I... `( •_•)>⌐■-■`  understand outstanding newfoundland `(⌐■_■)`

Comment: As long as you understand the pronunciation - which I'm pretty sure you do, based on that.

Comment: @StepHen Well, there are compressed strings too, so nah most probably not.

Comment: Can we print an array of arrays something like: `[["a", "an", "and"],["hand", "hands", "handle", "handles"],...]`

Comment: @Riley that's stretching it, 1 delimiter inbetween each word, though I can see many situations where that'd help :P.

Comment: FYI the three length 1 words do not appear in the unsorted.txt

Comment: Are we allowed to use different (although non-alphabetic) delimiters between our words? For example [this](https://tio.run/##AUcAuP9qZWxsef//4oCcwqHhu6TEscateiBYal0i4rGuKkFKxqTKguG6oTXGrOG5muG5qsOwXsal4bukwrvhuLLhuZYsJOKCrEf//w), would save me two bytes while maintaining Latin-text-read-order. EDIT - looks like your answer to Riley would imply a "no" I think.

Comment: @JonathanAllan just did :).

Comment: [Utility](https://gist.github.com/Jim-Bar/8583ccf50331d2962c4aeec064c2a6f4) for choosing the words.

Comment: @Jim hehe... I wrote something similar.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>49 35 31</s>  30 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṫ3,⁸Ṗ,$€ẎK
“¤ƈȮⱮ⁴⁷ọḤƁŒ|⁾Ė»ḲÇ€K
```

A niladic link returning a list of characters, or a full program printing that list as a string (the words delimited by spaces).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUsAtP9qZWxsef//4bmrMyzigbjhuZYsJOKCrOG6jksK4oCcwqTGiMiu4rGu4oG04oG34buN4bikxoHFknzigb7ElsK74biyw4figqxL//8)**

#### How?

```
ṫ3,⁸Ṗ,$€ẎK - Helper link: list of characters, word    e.g. "abreacts"
ṫ3         - tail word from index 3                          "reacts"
   ⁸       - chain's left argument, word
  ,        - pair                               ["reacts","abreacts"]
      $€   - last two links as a monad for €ach of the two words:
    Ṗ      -   pop (all but last character)      "react" / "abreact"
     ,     -   pair       ["react","reacts"] / ["abreact","abreacts"]
        Ẏ  - tighten          ["react","reacts","abreact","abreacts"]
         K - join with spaces         "react reacts abreact abreacts"

“¤ƈȮⱮ⁴⁷ọḤƁŒ|⁾Ė»ḲÇ€K - Link: no arguments
“¤ƈȮⱮ⁴⁷ọḤƁŒ|⁾Ė»     - a compressed string using dictionary indexes:
                    -   "agar abreacts acknowledges codeterminations deindustrializations"
               Ḳ    - split at spaces
                Ç€  - call the last link (Helper) as a monad for €ach
                  K - join with spaces
```

...which yields:

```
a ar aga agar react reacts abreact abreacts knowledge knowledges acknowledge acknowledges determination determinations codetermination codeterminations industrialization industrializations deindustrialization deindustrializations
```

---

Previous:

@35:

```
“¡Ụıƭz Xj]"Ɱ*AJƤʂạ5ƬṚṪð^ƥỤ»ḲṖ,$€K€K
```

Using 10 words and their length-1 prefixes.

@49

```
“ḊAḥTz¹ỴH¡ṛYẈDƤNŀt#ñ²ĿĊḤlṪnð⁻U+ɦỴĊypṆQ0⁴ṄẉṂi⁻d¤&»
```

Simply 20 compressed words.

Comment: Darn Jelly dictionary! +1

Comment: I didn't know Jelly had a dictionary, to be honest.

Comment: 30 BYTES!??!!??! I just went to sleep and woke up and it's as low as 30 BYTES?!!??!?!11 O_O_O

Comment: 30 BYTES!?!?!??! I FORGOT ABOUT THIS CHALLENGE FOR A MONTH AND HE WON WITH 30 BYTES!?!?!

Answer (score 27):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 145 bytes

```python
print'i am now tiny @ @s##s#ed#act#acts#@#@s#@ed#@ing#arguments#accusation#accusations#advertisings'.replace('#',' counter').replace('@','check')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcpBCgIxDIXhqwSyiAPiwhP0KiUTZoJOWtpUmdPXuNLFg5@PV0/fi93nrE3NSSEfYOUNrnZCgtQRO8qKmf27jgnDUkhS2zC3bRxi4Zl59Oxa7C@D15c01x7nTrcm9ZlZLoR0JeAyzKXR8vMUzrvwg5Y5Pw)

Prints these words, separated by spaces:

```python
i
am
now
tiny
check
checks
counter
counters
countered
counteract
counteracts
countercheck
counterchecks
counterchecked
counterchecking
counterarguments
counteraccusation
counteraccusations
counteradvertisings
```

Comment: "i am now tiny" - I like the self-descriptive code...

Answer (score 15):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>166</s> 163 bytes

```powershell
'a
an
and'
'','s','le','ler','lers'|%{"hand$_"}
($a="character")
($x=-split"s ed ful ized istic istics ization izations istically ologically"|%{"$a$_"})
"un"+$x[8]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1hCsIwDIX/9xQlVNKBHmFnkWyrthDa0XSIU89e64qQfHnJC7w1PVwW75hrRVIUWy2oEM8ordkdyJ2C79MLfPswV/goa2iE2VOmubgMg7rIyqGAaLfo28Y67E0EKWHulHahElL8T9HGWjONeNjE/MRh0InTvW/wyzN0pMEWm5qg1i8)

Hand-optimized, no algorithms. The two loops `|%{ }` tack on the appropriate ending to the appropriate beginning. I'm searching for a way to get them down into one loop.

Comment: Wow, my example looks even dumber now xD! `characterful > newfoundland`

Answer (score 10):

## Python, 169 bytes

```py
z='odahs princesses acclimatizers cyanocobalamines aerothermodynamics underrepresentations'.split()
print([y[:i+1]for x,y in zip(['']+z,z)for i in range(len(x),len(y))])
```

Prints a list of the words.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FczBCsMgEATQe7/Cm0pDofRW6JeEHKzZNgtmV3YtRH/extPAG2ZyLRvTo/f2sryGTU0WpAiqoCbEmHAPBRuImlgDceR3SGFHGjUIlw1k57XSaVHNj1YQgSygQOVcMqm9aU5YnL@M6@LmOj/xel8@LOaYqkEyDbObrV2ubWp@OA6VQF9wCcgdfhpRvV98738)

Words gained by scanning sequences of matching words, by start or end of the word and starting from length 1 upwards or from length 20 downwords.

[Here is the script I used to get it.](https://gist.github.com/urielieli/10770ef6ddfcf811505806d28db71017) <sub>(the upward-start-matching one)</sub>

Comment: 171 bytes (it feels like it should be shorter, but it isn't): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBDoMgEEX3nsLMRghsmu6aeBLiYlTaTkIHM9BEvDyVunov7/@t5Hfke61i0wiCmSJjAAurj3sRmiN/l@Chw9EBzpi8JLBiwF@g4x9gKchxiTMG/BC3MRk435fETOupU7cJcVauuAeZ2/SM0u@29MT9QZtywzAZtKhbp1YF@eVV8Kx2bRuK1pOu9Qc "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>126 120</s>  112 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to Anders Kaseorg <sub>(I thought I'd migrated this from Python 3, but turns out I'd forgotten!)</sub>

A port of my Jelly answer works well in Python too...

```python
for w in"agar abreacts acknowledges codeterminations deindustrializations".split():print w[2:-1],w[2:],w[:-1],w,
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYhBCsJADAC/EnqyUAV77FfEQ9xNa3BNliSy6OdXSi8zzNRvPFXm3lc1aMAy4IYG@DDCFA6YXqKtUN7IIWmmIHuzYLCKQyaW/PEwxsK/Yw4Xr4XjNC7VWALabV7O1/u0e@cRU@9/)**

Prints:

```python
a ar aga agar react reacts abreact abreacts knowledge knowledges acknowledge acknowledges determination determinations codetermination codeterminations industrialization industrializations deindustrialization deindustrializations
```

Comment: Python 2 lets you end with `print w[2:-1],w[2:],w[:-1],w,` for −8 bytes.

Comment: Oh, oops I forgot about this or thought I'd done it - I have a TIO page open somewhere with that!

Comment: Thanks for that though!

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, 159 bytes

```javascript
_='a1an1and}}swwrwrs~~s~ed~ful~ized{{s~|~|s{ally~ologically1misx|s~1x}1hand|ization{~isticxcharacterw}le';for(i of'wx{|}~')with(_.split(i))_=join(pop());f=f=>_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYu7joMwEAB/JR12cUjUiPsVZPkRNvKxlncTk9jeXyecNMUUMw/zMmQzJP7Z0fnzXJfBTGa/cL1TKblkEiHxTsIzCny8q5WkSaNqYnwLRryD/dfpD@hoJNPRp@36G3wMA@5VgBjsYTeTjWWfS49@mANmBTcMQzlq6zLoArypdaQUgRVovS4PhF0lTErrOSxh@V3POWW0nmgkdvjksWRgr8JVnF8)

Thanks @HyperNeutrino for edit. But, I am reverting back to old post (removing "Node.js" flag) because it has nothing to do with Node.js. It perfectly works in browsers too.

Comment: `f=f=>_` threw me off, I was like "won't that override the function" (it would just prevent recursion)

Comment: @StepHen. I'm not sure if leaving a plain string is allowed. As I understood, the code should represent a function (or whole program), thats why I added it to the end. Variable `_` already contains the string.

Comment: You're correct, I was just really confused as to what it did, since you reused the variable name (`f` as both function name and (ignored) parameter name)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 51 bytes

```
’¯Óa‚‡’D“€…€¤Þ¨íÊƒé¢Ã¥£žÜ¶ß´ç…àçî×Ü»‡Ûà³ŒçÓs²® ÿ ÿs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYxbCoJgFIS30hLswR20EQNX4AYO9dajPogXSrtZkAYpvggGM9hCzkb@DgwfzMcwnh9s16FzKhneTAKVXKW2tlEpdfdSuRtx5REPtjz8Yj5x5h43XJaZJUaeMLCxHSs27JianOyDBSv0S2wyifBBt@LXEjn3Bw)

Separator:

List of words: `a, an, ana, anal, house, houses, amazing, criminal, seriously, apparently, accessories, disciplinary, distributions, discrimination, congratulations, responsibilities, characterizations, telecommunications, representationalist, representationalists`

Comment: ***want to participate in own challenge intensifies***

Comment: I'm guessing 05AB1E has no 20-length words in the dictionary :P? Have yet to actually check myself.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn [Nope](https://tio.run/##Dca5TgJRAIbR2nkKMp2JGjCxtTKxo9PYauIrmFiYXBFx3wA3RGSGfRFwBxRI/i9j41vcF0GakxNeWN@IbI7Hro01rcn8Jq3JWVO2Jm@N95ewphNM1guSwcAa35qUNWkb9wPPmn6QCoZBV558FVRUSWVVVFVNdTXUVEttdfSiV73pXR/61Je66qmvb/1ooKFGGHaJsUecfRIccMgRx5xwyhnnXHDJFUlSpLnmhlvuuCfDA1keyfFEHg@fAkVKlKlQpUadBk2eadF2l/AdZ2s75FqTZTTBnVvdmV5xnPnI8lqUXphq1GU0NbsYCjFyZ8bjfw).

Comment: @adnan wow, that approach... may actually be a good idea if you can find a way to generate all dictionary code-points in like `1-10` bytes...

Comment: @adnan *Raises eyebrows* [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//2NYgI2OLozsMjY28jUxNnbxcDi/6/x8A "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Hmm, that also contains some 'non-dictionary' words, it is possible that this approach could be smaller.

Comment: @adnan that was my first attempt, I'm sure you could knock it outta the park.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 120 bytes

```
j=3
$><<?a
"  5  T &  }   <    ".bytes{|i|puts
8.times{|k|$><<%w{dehydro chlori ge n at ion e s}[k]*(j>>7-k&1)}
j+=i-31}
```

Prints the following. Each word is built from the 8 strings above, using the binary digits of `j` to select. On each iteration of the loop, `j` is incremented by the ASCII value of the characters in the string in quotes, minus 31.

```
a
es
ion
ions
nates
nation
nations
chlorine
chlorines
chlorinate
chlorinates
chlorination
dehydrogenate
dehydrogenates
dehydrogenation
dehydrogenations
dehydrochlorinate
dehydrochlorinates
dehydrochlorination
dehydrochlorinations
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 74 bytes

*Psychopathologically adventuresomenesses*

```
.e:"psychopathologicallyadventuresomenesses"b+bhkiR36"GGGGBKMMKKM6K6M0K0K0
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.e%3A%22psychopathologicallyadventuresomenesses%22b%2BbhkiR36%22GGGGBKMMKKM6K6M0K0K0&debug=0&input_size=4) It outputs:

```
['a', 'al', 'all', 'ally', 'logic', 'advent', 'venture', 'ventures', 'adventure', 'adventures', 'venturesome', 'pathological', 'adventuresome', 'pathologically', 'venturesomeness', 'psychopathologic', 'adventuresomeness', 'psychopathological', 'adventuresomenesses', 'psychopathologically']
```

Which, once formatted yields:

```
a
al
all
ally
logic
advent
venture
ventures
adventure
adventures
venturesome
pathological
adventuresome
pathologically
venturesomeness
psychopathologic
adventuresomeness
psychopathological
adventuresomenesses
psychopathologically
```

**Explanation**

The key was to choose two words that complement each other. I chose "*psychopathologically*" and "*adventuresomenesses*" thanks to [a little tool I wrote](https://gist.github.com/Jim-Bar/8583ccf50331d2962c4aeec064c2a6f4). Using these two words, for any length we can find substrings which are actual words of the [provided list](https://github.com/carusocomputing/wordListsByLength). All the possible decompositions are demonstrated by:

```
a al all ally logic psycho logical          logically pathologic             pathological               pathologically                 psychopathologic                   psychopathological                     psychopathologically
a ad ess ness esses advent venture ventures adventure adventures venturesome              adventuresome                venturesomeness                  adventuresomeness                    adventuresomenesses
```

The next step is just to get the list of the indexes for a given decomposition. For my decomposition, I chose: `16 16 16 16 11 20 22 22 20 20 22 6 20 6 22 0 20 0 20 0`, which are indexes in the concatenated strings: `psychopathologicallyadventuresomenesses`.

Finally, write a program which just loops over the indexes and display the substring at each given index with increasing length.

For saving bytes, I stored the indexes in a base 36 string. Indeed, `GGGGBKMMKKM6K6M0K0K0` is the list of my indexes in base 36 (because my highest index is 22, I could have used base 23).

**Program explanation**

```
.e:"psychopathologicallyadventuresomenesses"b+bhkiR36"GGGGBKMMKKM6K6M0K0K0

                                                 iR36"GGGGBKMMKKM6K6M0K0K0    # For each character in the string, convert from base 36 to base 10
.e                                                                            # Loop over indexes: b are the indexes, h their position
  :"psychopathologicallyadventuresomenesses"b+bhk                             # In "psy...ses", select the substring at index b and of length k + 1
```

Comment: psychopathologically - "In terms of the scientific study of mental disorders." Interesting.

Answer (score 4):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 66 bytes

```
00000000: 6d8b 410a 0020 0804 bf6a 4407 a134 5aff  m.A.. ...jD..4Z.
00000010: 4fe6 29ac 93ce b0a3 543a ad06 3f6c e769  O.).....T:..?l.i
00000020: 46f3 3ae2 b218 abc4 2cab d389 a805 82aa  F.:.....,.......
00000030: fee1 6e43 2444 62df 0f46 4a1e f356 8cf1  ..nC$Db..FJ..V..
00000040: 73d8                                     s.
```

Output:

```
o`al`res`alit`reset`preset`present`rational`represent`rationales`annotations`connotations`connotational`representation`representations`representational`misrepresentation`misrepresentations`representationalism`representationalisms
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc@9TsNAEEXhnqe4BQ0SGs3ujNdrNwgRpaChQRR0sz8TgRIalOc3DrGoOQ/wSaecSzn2w/m0LLw1I7VcoIENzJHBmRXFk0GVR1gQxWDuwIkeiUBEnzsifaebqxBWQ70nxMkqJqkdhU0wqBiscYJ4quhjmoAXuqNLrzPRw5E@NiNejOQCsR5RYsiwUhWxWkGTPMEyD8jRDNjT/Gvc07XNkNXw3gNSV0FUVaTYHOyaoBY6XIaEXD1gvfh6ut0Vov0z0dufoasxSsv4T9@0LD8)

The words and separator were selected by simulated annealing:

```python
from __future__ import print_function
import math
import random
import zlib

wordlists = \
    [[chr(x).encode() for x in [9, 10] + list(range(32, 127)) if not chr(x).encode().isalpha()]] + \
    [open('wordListsByLength/{}.txt'.format(n), 'rb').read().splitlines() for n in range(1, 21)]

words = [random.choice(wordlist) for wordlist in wordlists]

temperature = 10.
score = 9999
best = score

while True:
    old_score = score
    n = random.randrange(len(wordlists))
    old_word = words[n]
    words[n] = random.choice(wordlists[n])
    z = zlib.compressobj(9, zlib.DEFLATED, -zlib.MAX_WBITS, 9)
    score = len(z.compress(words[0].join(words[1:])) + z.flush())
    if score > old_score and random.random() >= math.exp((old_score - score) / temperature):
        words[n] = old_word
        score = old_score
    else:
        temperature *= .99999
        if score < best:
            best = score
            print(best, repr(words[0].join(words[1:])))
```

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 259 bytes

```c#
_=>{var a=new int[7].Select((n,i)=>"abasers".Substring(0,i+1)).ToList();a.Add("abacuses");a.AddRange(new int[12].Select((n,i)=>(i>10?"un":"")+"character"+"|s|ed|ful|ised|istic|istics|isation|isations|istically|ologically|istically|".Split('|')[i]));return a;}
```

Some obvious room for golfing still but I've run out of time now. I know it's longer than hard coding so will fix it when I get some time later on.

Comment: Woops is actually even longer because I need to include `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Just returning them in a string split by spaces is like 245.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I know that's what I said in my answer...

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>130</s> 68 bytes

-62 bytes thanks to [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer)

```
743222’€Ü†š ƒ´aî³eros €‡a•¿f²Ñns …¿en®íizers ‚ÀÙŠs ‡åØŽ’#‚øε`ηRs£R}˜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcsxDsIwDIXhu2RjIxJQTsA9XNdtLRG7clIGJG7CzBXYWZG4UiBmfP@nt91DH6nWAGnNZDl8ngHBoGch0za70@txC6MaJBYeyUBajtH7MmvRTJK58PX/jzuXCw@kqPJ7kCDL5HZwMxhYlxksAdJaGOHsemy6ed9r/QI)

Takes as many prefixes as needed from each of the following words:

```
amusers
carabinero
foraminiferans
photosensitizers
videoconferencings
radiopharmaceuticals
```

Prints these words in an array:

```
a
am
amu
amus
amuse
amuser
amusers
carabine
carabiner
carabinero
carabineros
foraminifera
foraminiferan
foraminiferans
photosensitizer
photosensitizers
videoconferencing
videoconferencings
radiopharmaceutical
radiopharmaceuticals
```

Comment: [You can significantly golf this (-43).](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcPMR01rDs951LDg6EIg59x2IHFs0qEtiYfXHdqcWpRfDBY0dzu0rBai9lHDwsRHDYsO7U87tOnwxDyIvKEhTEHDskP7U/MOrTu8NrMqtQgqawKXnXW44fDMowug4mZw8YWHlx6ecXQvRNgCJKx5es7//wA)

Comment: [And another -13.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcPMR01rDs951LDg6EIg59x2IHFs0qEtiYfXHdqcWpRfDBY0dzu0rBai9lHDwsRHDYsO7U87tOnwxDyIfJDxocVBIPmGZYf2p@YdWnd4bWZValGxwqOGWYcbDs88ugDEXHh46eEZR/cC1Smf2wrUZATUVKt5es7//wA)

Comment: [Some other -6 too...](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f3MTYyMjoUcPMR01rDs951LDg6EKFY5MObUk8vO7Q5tSi/GIFoMSjhoWJjxoWHdqfdmjT4Yl5QLGGZYf2p@YdWnd4bWZVahFIYNbhhsMzjy4AMRceXnp4xtG9QEOVQeI7zm1NOLc9qPjQ4qDa03P@/wcA) (sadly I can't replace `743222` with `•B/™•`)

Comment: Yeah, you don't need the `S` so it's -62 bytes. ;)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thanks! I was trying to do something like that last one, but I couldn't make it work. Do you mind explaining how the compressed strings works?

Comment: `’` means "no-implicit-space compressed string". Then there's the [compressor](https://tio.run/##VVHJTgJRELz7FS/j1Rg5eCYm/oAHjQcvAz5xkpEhM6jBxOSpiPsGrojLjMou4I4LkHRlvPgX70dwMB60Dp1Op7pSXd3XrwZ8vN1WpMgofvYXSsTkWliLaqquzXEWNKa8gWXxcWZFTS0cUsa6uvQB1KiEJa/a/zaNoEdlWjgyHfV4M7Fh9l97wjAZV4OTHRFFLpalSH8mpTiXIivFpRT2V0KKmut1r27SbUjhSJGSYl/GHdeW4s1NuU23TjY5dEXXdENZylGeClSkEpWpQlWq0R3d0wM90hM90wvV6ZXe6J0@qEFNakFgAYue9TiWkcAKVrGGdWxgE1vYxg52sYckUtjHAQ5xhGOcII1TZHCGc1zgEjYcXOEaN8gihzwKKKKEMm5RQVUZhMOUEA9zU41ypuo6ixiWpQV0zmYNc9zqnD4T6wSPVif93pFRfUiL@X3d87/4eUpPux0xdNVkAa6a3w) which would compress the words.

Comment: Note that only 100 different chars are used to compress words, the others (like `s`) are put verbatim into the string. Every word is 2 chars, and there are 10000 words. Each char is assigned an *index* from 00 to 99. Two such chars make a 4-digit number (leading zero matters) from 0000 to 9999. That's the index of the particular word. The chars are in order: `€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ•–—™š›œžŸ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîï`. Quote types include `“` (normal), `”` (titlecase), `‘` (uppercase) and `’` (no implicit space).

Answer (score 2):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 78 bytes

```
00000000: 654b c301 4431 10bd a7cb d876 9a5f efe7  eK..D1.....v._..
00000010: 781e 2080 ee55 0488 ffc8 9f69 e86f a5ff  x. ..U.....i.o..
00000020: ce00 0b98 202e 34ed d701 a464 bf59 35fb  .... .4....d.Y5.
00000030: 23d7 9192 b948 7c79 f351 0c8b f4ee 06e4  #....H|y.Q......
00000040: 8b05 1a33 77c8 1bcf 7f58 7577 e113       ...3w....Xuw..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc87TwQxDATgnl8xEr0Vbx5OqCmQqCiQoELrxEZIIKrjIfHfl@wdxzSu5tNYD6qv9nx427bwlyuUnBQ9BkZKkcFBB1bpilGloK3ZYW4C2C3RNdOeD3oiujgJPA2pbFhCDTDLGSHVCvde0bw0WC2O6TjwRSC6Pxov9P5vLNPoFgKCtjqhxRCTDQyZs9ZUEtRzQ8yuwF4Gpf0MesxnI05jiUPQuC3QliqkS4PHzAi9KjyZIRRLwOXevvn5prvjlrORplE1ZPAaI0TmB6zdIZ6nlkVgzBGnzFr83MsPh3m27Rc)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 107 bytes

```
p(z=%w{o or for form ultra})+[z[3],c="centrifug",z[4]+c].product(%w{ed ing ally ation ations}).map{|i|i*""}
```

Prints the following array.

```
["o", "or", "for", "form", "ultra", "formed", "forming", "formally", "formation", "formations", "centrifuged", "centrifuging", "centrifugally", "centrifugation", "centrifugations", "ultracentrifuged", "ultracentrifuging", "ultracentrifugally", "ultracentrifugation", "ultracentrifugations"
```

Changing the `p` for `puts` (with trailing space) gives the following at a cost of an additional 4 bytes.

```
o
or
for
form
ultra
formed
forming
formally
formation
formations
centrifuged
centrifuging
centrifugally
centrifugation
centrifugations
ultracentrifuged
ultracentrifuging
ultracentrifugally
ultracentrifugation
ultracentrifugations
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 119 bytes

```
`av„v„dvjvjsvj¤vj¤svfœejvqvqsvq‚vqˆgvqizƒvqÄKcvqÄKcsvqizÂ\nvqizÂ\nsvq‰tkvqologkv·sqizÂ\ns`d'j`Ê@`'k`Åœ§`'q`Ö‹a×` q'v ·
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYo9CsJAFISv4BHS7TXsvYLFW4wG3wbjY8MUljGCP702KQMeIf17B1uzSGC@GZgZ9uc2JfLQflYJBkewjpmIgw57hkAiRLuZewU5XvQKsX6z@3vMlXXb05L5/GgDpKmbKkCnuAxUOiZ7rskFspsO@iUnZG99efusqBCHQqeUfg)

### Prints:

```
a
an
and
hand
hands
handle
handles
freehand
character
characters
charactered
charactering
characterizes
characteristic
characteristics
characterization
characterizations
characteristically
characterologically
mischaracterizations
```